# Call URL from console without opening in any browser

Tags: google-chrome, unix, browser

I have a browser controllable smart pluck outlet, which I can control by calling a URL. I know I am aware of the command

```
open http://192.168.1.175/cgi-bin/relay.cgi?off
```

But that opens a tab in the default browser (which is chrome). Is there any way to call the url without actually causing my browser to open a new tab? Could I somehow call the url "in the background"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use curl or wget for this purpose:

```
curl http://192.168.1.175/cgi-bin/relay.cgi?off

wget http://192.168.1.175/cgi-bin/relay.cgi?off
```

If you need to use a method other than GET, curl is more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers of curl and wget are good ones. For a slightly more obscure method, you could also issue the HTTP command yourself over a socket. For example...

```
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n" | nc www.google.com 80
```

Comment: You can use good old telnet command also :)